# React onMouseEnter not firing in Chrome when element blocking cursor disappears

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

**NOTE: This appears to be a Chrome only issue**

React will currently not fire the `onMouseEnter` event when an element blocking the event element disappears. This is not the case with standard JS events and even delegated events.

Here is a simplified depiction and code sample of the issue I am having; when the tooltip from the lower element disappears (and the cursor is above the upper element), the `onMouseEvent` does not fire:

[image: React onMouseEnter event does not fire when element blocking cursor disappears]

```js
function reactMouseEnter({currentTarget}) {
  console.log('React Mouse Enter Event');
  const rect = currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
  const tooltip = document.createElement('div');
  tooltip.classList.add('tooltip');
  tooltip.style.top = rect.y - 30 + 'px';
  document.body.appendChild(tooltip);

  const mouseLeaveHandler = () => {
    currentTarget.removeEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);
    setTimeout(() => {
      tooltip.parentNode.removeChild(tooltip);
    }, 300);
  };

  currentTarget.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef()
  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref.current.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      console.log('Regular Mouse Enter Event');
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onMouseEnter={ reactMouseEnter } ref={this.ref} className="box" />
        <div onMouseEnter={ reactMouseEnter } className="box" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example /> , document.getElementById('example'));
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 28px;
}

.tooltip {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="example" style="margin-top: 30px;"></div>
```

Is there something I can do differently in React to get `onMouseEnter` to work? I also tried using `onMouseOver` instead, but it produces other unintended side effects in my actual implementation, so would prefer to see if this is possible with `onMouseEnter`.

Answer (score 5):

This is technically intended because onMouseEnter only fires on the border of the element. You want to use onMouseOver.

You can see this [demo comparison here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_over_enter), the center box with the counter is not part of the element so use that to test.

Comment: I updated my question to better reflect that standard JavaScript events are still fired, even when the issue at hand is present. If you re-run my example above, you will see that the regular event is fired, while the react one is not.

Comment: @KevBot Simply change your `onMouseEnter`s to `onMouseOver`. Worked for me.

Comment: @KevBot you wont be able to get it working with onMouseEnter but if you let us know what the unintended side affects youre facing I can try to help. You can always add a condition check to onMouseOver.