# Button turning to wrong color with onMouse events and state

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom-events

I am currently creating a profile for a user on my app, however, when I add functionality to add coloring to the button, the button turns red versus green and stays at the color red when the mouse is not 'inside' the button. I want the button to be green the first time around so it only turns red when you hover your mouse over the button...

Here is the code in question:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import userInformation from "../../services/userInformation";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import VectorIllustration from "./VectorIllustration";
import AvatarPicture from '../../images/AvatarPicture.png'
import HomeTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HomeTwoTone';
import { Avatar } from "@nextui-org/react";
import PageviewTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PageviewTwoTone';
import GroupsTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/GroupsTwoTone';
import EmailTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EmailTwoTone';
import SettingsApplicationsTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SettingsApplicationsTwoTone';
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import ImageTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ImageTwoTone';
import VideocamTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VideocamTwoTone';
import AttachFileTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AttachFileTwoTone';
import SendTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SendTwoTone';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { storePostURLs, storeUserInformation } from "../../reducers/storeInformationReducer";
import { createPosts } from "../../reducers/postReducer";
import { Loading } from '@nextui-org/react'
import ErrorTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ErrorTwoTone';
import CheckBoxTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxTwoTone';
import DeleteForeverTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteForeverTwoTone';
import postInformation from "../../services/postInformation";

const Home = () => {
  const state = useSelector(state => state)
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('')
  const [contentError, setContentError] = useState('')
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [deleteItem, setDeleteItem] = useState(false)
  const [deleteVideo, setDeleteVideo] = useState(false)
  const [deleteDocument, setDeleteDocument] = useState(false)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  console.log(state)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(deleteDocument)
    const user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loggedAppUser'))
    console.log(user)
    async function findUserWithToken() {
      userInformation.setToken(user.token)
      const response = await userInformation.findUser(user.user.email)
      const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(response.data.user)
      const arrayOfValues = Object.values(response.data.user)
      let i = 0
      arrayOfKeys.forEach(element => {
        dispatch(storeUserInformation(arrayOfValues[i], element))
        i++
      });
    }
    findUserWithToken()
}, [deleteDocument])

const handleNewPost = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(state.newPost)
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfKeys.length; i++) {
    if (arrayOfKeys[i] in state.newPost && arrayOfKeys[i] !== 'text' && ((arrayOfKeys[i] === 'image' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]].size < 10485760) || (arrayOfKeys[i] === 'video' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]].size < 104857600) || 
    (arrayOfKeys[i] === 'document' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]].size < 10485760))) {
      try {
        setLoading(true) 
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('file', state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]]);
        formData.append('upload_preset', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_PRESET)
        formData.append('api_key', process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_APIKEY)
        if (arrayOfKeys[i] === 'image' || arrayOfKeys[i] === 'document') {
        await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_IMAGE_URL, formData).finally(el => {
          setLoading(false)
        })
        
      } else {
          await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_CLOUDINARY_VIDEO_URL, formData).finally(el => {
            setLoading(false)
          })
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        setErrorMessage('An error has occurred!')
        setContentError(arrayOfKeys[i])
        setTimeout(() => {
          setErrorMessage('')
          setContentError('')
          setLoading(false)
        }, 5000)
      } finally {
        postInformation.makeAPost(state.newPost)
        arrayOfKeys.forEach((key) => {
          dispatch(createPosts('', key))
        })
      }
    } else if (arrayOfKeys[i] !== 'text' && state.newPost[arrayOfKeys[i]]){
      console.log(state.newPost)
      setErrorMessage('Video files must be 100MB or less, images and documents must be 10MB or less.')
      setContentError(arrayOfKeys[i])
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage('')
        setContentError('')
      }, 5000)
    }
  }
}


  return (
    <>
    <div style={{
      position: 'relative',
      width: '1920px',
      height: '1080px',
      background: '#F7F9FE'}}>
      <VectorIllustration />
      <h1 style={{position: 'absolute', width: '30%', height: '5%', left: '20%', top: '4%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '400', fontSize: '32px', lineHeight: '40px', color: '#000000'}}>Welcome {state.storage.name}!</h1>
      <Link to='/home' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '2%', top: '20%', background: 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.47) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 93.56%)', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Home</Link>
      <HomeTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '21.5%', fontSize: '225%'}} color='primary' />
      <Avatar src={state.storage.profileImageURL ? state.storage.profileImageURL : AvatarPicture} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '83.5%', top: '11%', height: '132px', width: '132px'}}></Avatar>
      <Link to='/findasponsor' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '3.5%', top: '29%', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Find A Sponsor</Link>
      <PageviewTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '30.5%', fontSize: '225%', opacity: '0.7'}} />
      <Link to='/Groups' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '3.5%', top: '37%', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Groups</Link>
      <GroupsTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '38.6%', fontSize: '225%', opacity: '0.75'}}  />
      <Link to='/Messsages' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '3.5%', top: '45%', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Messages</Link>
      <EmailTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '46.5%', fontSize: '225%', opacity: '0.75'}} />
      <Link to='/Settings' style={{position: 'absolute', width: '10%', height: '6.5%', left: '3.5%', top: '54%', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column'}}>Settings</Link>
      <SettingsApplicationsTwoToneIcon style={{position: 'absolute', left: "3%", top: '55.5%', fontSize: '225%', opacity: '0.75'}} />
      <h1 style={{position: 'absolute', width: '201px', height: '76px', left: '4%', top: '68%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '500', fontSize: '26px', lineHeight: '38px', textAlign: 'center', color: '#1B1C1F', textDecoration: 'underline'}}>Go Local</h1>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', width: '201px', height: '76px', left: '4%', top: '73%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '500', fontSize: '15px', textAlign: 'center', color: 'black'}}>Currently, you are viewing sponsors/ sponsees globally. Would you like to view only sponsors/sponsees in your country?</p>
      <Button style={{position: 'absolute', left: '4.5%', top: '85%', background: '#FFFFFF', borderRadius: '16px'}}>No</Button>
      <Button style={{position: 'absolute', left: '10.5%', top: '85%', background: '#FFFFFF', borderRadius: '16px'}} onClick={(e) => navigate('./Settings')}>Yes</Button>
      <h1 style={{position: 'absolute', top: '70%', left: '78%'}}>Trending Users</h1>
      <Link to='/home/:id' style={{position: 'absolute', top: '73.25%', left: '94%'}}>View all</Link>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '20%', left: '79%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '600', fontSize: '20px', lineHeight: '25px', textAlign: 'center'}}>{state.storage.followers}</p>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '23%', left: '77.5%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '300', fontSize: '16px', lineHeight: '20px', textAlign: 'center', color: '#A2ADBC'}}>Followers</p>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '20%', left: '94.5%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '600', fontSize: '20px', lineHeight: '25px', textAlign: 'center'}}>{state.storage.following}</p>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '23%', left: '93%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '300', fontSize: '16px', lineHeight: '20px', textAlign: 'center', color: '#A2ADBC'}}>Following</p>      
      <h1 style={{position: 'absolute', top: '28%', left: '83.6%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '500', fontSize: '20px', lineHeight: '25px', textAlign: 'center'}}>{state.storage.name}</h1>
      <p style={{position: 'absolute', width: '360px', height: '54px', left: '77.6%', top: '33%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '300', fontSize: '14px', lineHeight: '18px', textAlign: 'center', color: '#6D7683'}}>{state.storage.biography}</p>
      
      <form onSubmit={handleNewPost}>
      {contentError ? <TextField disabled size="large" rows={5} inputProps={{maxLength: 500}} multiline style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '38%', width: '20%', color: 'red'}} value={errorMessage} /> : <TextField required size="large" rows={5} inputProps={{maxLength: 500}} multiline style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '38%', width: '20%'}} placeholder='How are you feeling?' value={state.newPost.text} disabled={loading} onChange={(e) => {
        dispatch(createPosts(e.target.value, 'text'))
      }} />}  


      {state.newPost.image ? <Button onMouseEnter={() => setDeleteItem(!deleteItem)} onMouseLeave={() => setDeleteItem(!deleteItem)} onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createPosts('', 'image'))
      }} startIcon={deleteItem ? <DeleteForeverTwoToneIcon /> : <CheckBoxTwoToneIcon />} variant='contained' color={deleteItem ? "error" : "success"} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '78%', top: '53%', borderRadius: '16px'}}>1 Image</Button> : <Button startIcon={contentError === 'image' ? <ImageTwoToneIcon style={{color: 'red'}}/> : <ImageTwoToneIcon />} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '53%', background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32)', border: '1px solid rgba(45, 135, 255, 0.3)', borderRadius: '16px', color: contentError === 'image' ? 'red' : '', borderColor: contentError === 'image' ? 'red' : ''}} disabled={loading} component='label'>Add Image <input style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}} accept="image/*" type='file' hidden onChange={(e) => {
        setDeleteItem(false)
        dispatch(createPosts(e.target.files[0], 'image'))
      }}/></Button>}


      {state.newPost.video ? <Button onMouseLeave={() => setDeleteVideo(!deleteVideo)} onMouseEnter={() => setDeleteVideo(!deleteVideo)} onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createPosts('', 'video'))
      }} startIcon={deleteVideo ? <DeleteForeverTwoToneIcon /> : <CheckBoxTwoToneIcon />} variant='contained' color={deleteVideo ? "error" : "success"} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '85%', top: '53%', borderRadius: '16px'}}>1 Video</Button> : <Button startIcon={contentError === 'video' ? <VideocamTwoToneIcon style={{color: 'red'}}/> : <VideocamTwoToneIcon />} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '85%', top: '53%', background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32)', border: '1px solid rgba(45, 135, 255, 0.3)', borderRadius: '16px', color: contentError === 'video' ? 'red' : '', borderColor: contentError === 'video' ? 'red' : ''}} disabled={loading} component='label'>Add Video <input style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}} accept='video/*' type='file' hidden onChange={(e) => {
        setDeleteVideo(false)
        dispatch(createPosts(e.target.files[0], 'video'))
      }}/></Button>}


      {state.newPost.document ? <Button onMouseLeave={() => setDeleteDocument(!deleteDocument)} onMouseEnter={() => setDeleteDocument(!deleteDocument)} onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createPosts('', 'document'))
      }} startIcon={deleteDocument ? <DeleteForeverTwoToneIcon /> : <CheckBoxTwoToneIcon />} variant='contained' color={deleteDocument ? "error" : "success"} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '92.5%', top: '53%', borderRadius: '16px'}}>1 File</Button> : <Button startIcon={contentError === 'document' ? <AttachFileTwoToneIcon style={{color: 'red'}}/> : <AttachFileTwoToneIcon />} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '93%', top: '53%', background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32)', border: '1px solid rgba(45, 135, 255, 0.3)', borderRadius: '16px', color: contentError === 'document' ? 'red' : '', borderColor: contentError === 'document' ? 'red' : ''}} disabled={loading} component='label'>File <input style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}} accept=".pdf" type='file' hidden onChange={(e) => {
        
        dispatch(createPosts(e.target.files[0], 'document'))
      }}/></Button>}


      {loading ? <Button disabled startIcon={<Loading style={{fontSize: '175%'}} color='white'/>} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '58%', background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, #2D87FF 0%, #6099E5 100%)', borderRadius: '60px', color: 'white', width: '20.5%', height: '5%'}}>Loading</Button> : errorMessage ? <Button disabled startIcon={<ErrorTwoToneIcon color="white"/>} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '58%', background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, #2D87FF 0%, #6099E5 100%)', borderRadius: '60px', color: 'white', width: '20.5%', height: '5%'}}>Error</Button> : <Button type="submit" startIcon={<SendTwoToneIcon style={{fontSize: '175%'}} />} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '77%', top: '58%', background: 'linear-gradient(180deg, #2D87FF 0%, #6099E5 100%)', borderRadius: '60px', color: 'white', width: '20.5%', height: '5%'}}>Post</Button>}
      </form>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

And here is the specific code with the issue:

```
{state.newPost.document ? <Button onMouseLeave={() => setDeleteDocument(!deleteDocument)} onMouseEnter={() => setDeleteDocument(!deleteDocument)} onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createPosts('', 'document'))
      }} startIcon={deleteDocument ? <DeleteForeverTwoToneIcon /> : <CheckBoxTwoToneIcon />} variant='contained' color={deleteDocument ? "error" : "success"} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '92.5%', top: '53%', borderRadius: '16px'}}>1 File</Button> : <Button startIcon={contentError === 'document' ? <AttachFileTwoToneIcon style={{color: 'red'}}/> : <AttachFileTwoToneIcon />} variant="outlined" style={{position: 'absolute', left: '93%', top: '53%', background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.32)', border: '1px solid rgba(45, 135, 255, 0.3)', borderRadius: '16px', color: contentError === 'document' ? 'red' : '', borderColor: contentError === 'document' ? 'red' : ''}} disabled={loading} component='label'>File <input style={{pointerEvents: 'none'}} accept=".pdf" type='file' hidden onChange={(e) => {
        setDeleteDocument(false)
        dispatch(createPosts(e.target.files[0], 'document'))
      }}/></Button>}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution via this link:

[React onMouseEnter not firing in Chrome when element blocking cursor disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836826/react-onmouseenter-not-firing-in-chrome-when-element-blocking-cursor-disappears)

I had to switch from `onMouseEnter` to `onMouseOver` because `onMouseEnter` triggers when the border is hit versus `onMouseOver` triggers while over the element...